# jQuery stopPropagation for only some class of elements

Tags: jquery, events

I've got some `.myClass` elements with hover effect and I want only one of them at once to use hover event so i use:

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

But I also have `.myOtherClass` and need it to use that hover event too. When I use `event.stopPropagation()` it block event at all.

How to block event propagation on `.myClass` but dont block it for `.myOtherClass`?

[edit]

http://jsfiddle.net/K92Fe/ - on click (hover or whatever) I need only `one` alert telling what class is clicked (peak one)

Comment: it helps if you post your code in a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Here is what `event.stopPropagation` does: it prevents the event from being fired on the ancestors of the element at which the handler calls `stopPropagation`. It doesn't stop hover events from being fired on other elements.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're selecting both classes of elements at once, similar to `$(".myClass, .myOtherClass")`?

If so you can use `has()` in an `if` statement to only stopPropagation for the class required.

For example:

```
 $(".myClass, .myOtherClass").hover(function(e) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('myClass') {
          e.stopPropagation();
      };

      // hover logic
 });
```

---

**UPDATE**

With regards to your fiddle, you simply need to call `stopPropagation` in each event handler:

```
$(".a").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("a clicked");
});
$(".b").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert("b clicked");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/K92Fe/1/)