# Toggle class on element, ignore all but one child

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a hard time solving this even after reading [jQuery stopPropagation for only some class of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563360/jquery-stoppropagation-for-only-some-class-of-elements), [Javascript toggle class on element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348912/javascript-toggle-class-on-element) and countless other references.

I want to toggle class "active" when clicking on nav > ul > li AND .dd-toggle (a child of .dropdown) but NOT .dropdown itself or anything within it (other than .dd-toggle).

```
<nav class="nav-dropdowns" role="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class="">
            <span class="dropdown-title">Price</span>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dd-toggle">X</a>
                <div id="field-price" class="field"><label>Price Range</label>
                    <div class="details"></div>
                </div>
                </div> <button type="submit" class="extra-submit buttonstyle">Search</button>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <span class="dropdown-title">Type</span>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="dd-toggle">X</a>
                <div id="field-type" class="field"><label>Property Type</label>
                    <div class="details"></div>
                </div> <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="search-submit">
            <button class="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I have tried numerous variations starting with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "nav > ul > li" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).closest().toggleClass( "active" );
    });
});
```

then

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "nav > ul > li" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
    });
    $('.dropdown').click(function(e) {
      return false;
    });
});
```

and finally

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $( "nav > ul > li" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();      
    $( this ).toggleClass( "active" ).not('.dropdown');
    });
});
```

I get ignoring the children of or closest to, but can't figure out how to do that but still observe a child of the child. Perhaps only first child of?

Ignore .dropdown but NOT .dd-toggle

Am I close?

Comment: You're close. Just check if `this` has a class of ".dropdown", or has an ancestor with that class and does not have a class of "dd-toggle". If so, return false. Otherwise, get the closest `li` and toggle the "active" class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would really recommend reading:

[Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).  It will really reduce your tightly coupled code.

Everything in Green will change to red, unless you are in blue (in green).  Although I'm not sure (because you're question isn't clear) if you're asking for active on either the `li` and the `.dd-toggle` (as it is now) or only the `li` which wouldn't be hard.

If you need active only on the `li` simply change the `.dd-toggle` code  to:

```
$(this).parents('li').first().toggleClass('active');
```

[CodePen.IO Working Example](https://codepen.io/erikphilips/pen/Exaazpx)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("nav > ul > li").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).parents('.dropdown').length === 0 &&
      !$(e.target).hasClass('dropdown')) {
      $(this).toggleClass("active");
    }
  });
  $(".dd-toggle").on("click", function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
nav > ul > li, .dd-toggle {
  border: 2px solid green;  
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}

.active {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.dropdown {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-dropdowns" role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li class="">
      <span class="dropdown-title">Price</span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dd-toggle">X</a>
        <div id="field-price" class="field"><label>Price Range</label>
          <div class="details"></div>
        </div>
      </div> <button type="submit" class="extra-submit buttonstyle">Search</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <span class="dropdown-title">Type</span>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dd-toggle">X</a>
        <div id="field-type" class="field"><label>Property Type</label>
          <div class="details"></div>
        </div> <button type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="search-submit">
      <button class="search-button" type="submit">Search</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you @Erik Philips. My apologies for the delay in response - I came down with a mean case of something that took me out. Thank you for your response, and for recommending the decoupling article. I will read and learn from it. Thanks, too, for the code snippet. I will attempt to implement it and report back here. Happy holidays to you and yours.